# Self inductance & time constant formula

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, inductance

Is this a correct formula for calculating the induced EMF of a wire after the current stabilizes/ or while it stabilizes in the beginning  of a DC circuit?

[image]

What is the difference between the above and this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd equation *defines* the ideal inductor circuit element.  It is understood that the voltage $v$ and current $i$ in that equation are the voltage across and current through the inductor.

The inductor emf is the opposite sign of the inductor voltage.

$$\mathcal E_L = -v_L $$

Clearly, when the current 'stabilizes' (the time rate of change of the inductor current is effectively zero), the voltage and emf are zero.

The 1st equation is the time derivative of a particular solution for the series current of some RL circuit.  Do you have more context to provide for that equation?